# Google maps not fully loaded until map moved manually

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I`m developing an android app that is following the user using GPS and on every location update I`m recentering the map to the new location, slowly progressing out of the clearly downloaded map tiles. After a while, when the user has moved enough to get out of the initially downloaded map tiles area, the map is not loading properly, but if I move the map manually, it loads everything as expected.

There is one "hack" I`m doing here. If the user moves the map, I don`t want to keep recentering the map on every location update, so I set a global variable in this case and only recenter the map if the user didn`t move the map by hand:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
    mShouldFollowUserPosition = reason != GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add your code .

Comment: which part? I guess the only relevant part would be how I\`m moving the map, but that\`s pretty standard
`map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 15));`

Comment: Without any code no one can help .  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895696/android-mapview-does-not-load-unless-you-touch-on-the-mapview if you already haven't.

Comment: it looks like the problem was with the animation, using this answer it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915213/android-google-maps-api-v2-stops-loading-tiles